# Magento 1.9 Create Order From Cart via Skript

Tags: php, magento-1.9

I try to create an order with item from cart.
I've found a skript that worked on ssh in magento root, but when I call the skript via checkout/cart->skript-php I got 500 Server Error.

My Skript is here:

```html
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 
Mage::app();
 
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
        ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore('default')->getId());
 
$product = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getItems();
//$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(87561); /* 6 => Some product ID */
$buyInfo = array('qty' => 1);
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($buyInfo));
 
$billingAddress = array(
    'firstname' => 'Me',
    'lastname' => 'And',
    'company' => 'None',
    'email' =>  'asdf@asdf.com',
    'street' => array(
        'Sample Street Line_1',
        'Sample Street Line_2'
    ),
    'city' => 'City',
    'region_id' => '',
    'region' => 'State/Province',
    'postcode' => '12345',
    'country_id' => 'DE',
    'telephone' =>  '1234567890',
    'fax' => '123456987',
    'customer_password' => '',
    'confirm_password' =>  '',
    'save_in_address_book' => '0',
    'use_for_shipping' => '1',
);
$quote->getBillingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress);
$quote->getShippingAddress()
        ->addData($billingAddress)
        ->setShippingMethod('solutioo')
        ->setPaymentMethod('cashondelivery')
        ->setCollectShippingRates(true)
        ->collectTotals();
$quote->setCheckoutMethod('guest')
            ->setCustomerId(null)
            ->setCustomerEmail($quote->getBillingAddress()->getEmail())
            ->setCustomerIsGuest(true)
            ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID);
$quote->getPayment()->importData( array('method' => 'cashondelivery'));
$quote->save();
$service = Mage::getModel('sales/service_quote', $quote);
$service->submitAll();
//$order = $service->getOrder();
```

2 Questions:
1- How should I call the skript from Magento Cart so it will work?

2- Is this the right way to get the product

Hope somebody can help me, ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1: it's not very clear what your end goal is here, what are you *actually* trying to achieve. 2: the script looks a bit like a hack - it *feels* like you should be trying to use the SOAP API. 3: you should put the relevant code in the question, if Pastebin is down there's no code here. 4: you're asking 2 questions which would have 2 completely different solutions - so they should be 2 questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: My goal is to create a order with one click from Magento Cart.

Comment: Like a button on the cart page that bypasses the checkout and just creates an order with some default billing/shipping information? That would be a complete module you'll be starting from scratch on - unless there's already one out there. Though you've only got 6 months, Magento 1.9 hits end of life in June - by which point everything must be migrated to Magento 2 - which is different enough that you'll need to completely rebuild the module for that.

Comment: CD001: I know that Magento 1 goes end of life; this is why it should be simple as possible. A module is too complex.A Button in Cart is enough to create a prdefined order. How can this be done?